# How does MySQL handle compound unique indexes with limited lengths?

Tags: mysql, unique, compound-key

Assuming two columns in a MySQL (MyISAM) table:

```
title VARCHAR(1500)
url VARCHAR(155)
```

I want to create a composite unique index on both columns. I know of the *limiting length* feature for too long columns (like my `title` column). How does it play with compound indexes?

What I want is something like:

```
|--- url_value ---| + |--- title_value ---|
|--------155------| + |--------rest-------| <-- This should be the key length
```

By that I mean the key should have maximum length (I am using utf8 as encoding so I am limited to 333 characters allowed per column for unique indexes), where all 155 characters of column `url` and 178 characters of column `title` should be respected in the unique index. Sorry for the bad English. I tried to explain as well as I could. So bear with me if it seems confusing and I gladly will provide more information, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, so this may not really answer it, but one option for enforcing uniqueness on long fields like that is to instead enforce a unique constraint on a hash of the long fields, using MD5, or any other hashing algorithm that suits your needs.  So...

```
title VARCHAR(1500)
url VARCHAR(155)
title_md5 VARCHAR(16)
```

You could create a trigger that automatically populates `title_md5` every time `title` is updated.  Then you put your unique index on `(url,title_md5)`.

Of course this has some drawbacks.  There is more overhead in the actual table--although much of that can be offset by the smaller/more efficient index.  Also, indexing `title_md5` doesn't make searching the actual `title` column any faster, so you may need a "duplicate" index on `title`, if you need to do searching on that.